# C# Selenium Chrome Run Async from WPF without blocking main window

Tags: c#, wpf, selenium-webdriver, asynchronous, async-await

I am trying to run `Selenium` `asynchronously` from a WPF to retrieve some information which I will later use in WPF.
Selenium is running `headless`.
I am trying to run it on `Window_Loaded` `event`.
This is my code:

```
private async void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Uri url = new Uri("https://server/");
    UriBuilder ub = new UriBuilder(url);
    ub.UserName = "user";
    ub.Password = "pass";
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    ChromeDriverService chromeService = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
    chromeService.HideCommandPromptWindow = true;
    options.AddArgument("--headless");
    options.AddArgument("log-level=3");
    IWebDriver sDriver = new ChromeDriver(chromeService, options);
    sDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl(ub.Uri);
}
```

How can I run it async to avoid having WPF blocked?
Plus, how can I `interact` with the `MainWindow` after getting the result since we are in `async`?
What is the best practice here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If Selenium offers any async methods those are preferable. But if it doesn't, the nuclear option is to offload the code to a synchronous method and call it using `Task.Run`.

```
private void Foo(string uri)
{
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    ChromeDriverService chromeService = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
    chromeService.HideCommandPromptWindow = true;
    options.AddArgument("--headless");
    options.AddArgument("log-level=3");
    IWebDriver sDriver = new ChromeDriver(chromeService, options);
    sDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl(uri);
}

private async void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Uri url = new Uri("https://server/");
    UriBuilder ub = new UriBuilder(url);
    ub.UserName = "user";
    ub.Password = "pass";

    await Task.Run( () => Foo(ub.Uri) );
}
```

Comment: I am new to Selenium. I see the same problem with it not offering any async methods.
Thank you